# Access a bash array in awk loop

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have a bash array like

```
myarray = (1 2 3 4 5 ... n)
```

Also I am reading a file with an input of only one line for example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... n
```

I am reading it line by line into an array and printing it with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     NR>=1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i}
     END{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print OFS a[i]}' myfile.txt
```

`myarray` has the same size as `a`. Now `myarray` starts with the index `0` and `a` with index `1`. My main problem though is how I can pass the bash array to my awk expression so that I can use it inside the print loop with the corresponding elements. So what I tried was this:

```
awk -v array="${myarray[*]}"
    'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     NR>=1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i}
     END{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print OFS a[i] OFS array[i-1]}' myfile.txt
```

This doens't work though. I don't get any output for `myarray`. My desired output in this example would be:

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
...
n   n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, you just need to feed `awk` with the bash array in a correct way. That is, by using [`split()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html):

```
awk -v bash_array="${myarray[*]}" 
     'BEGIN{split(bash_array,array); FS=OFS="\t"}
      NR>=1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i} 
      END{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print a[i], array[i]}' file
```

Since the array `array[]` is now in `awk`, you don't have to care about the indices, so you can call them normally, without worrying about the ones in bash starting from `0`.

Note also that `print a,b` is the same (and cleaner) as `print a OFS b`, since you already defined `OFS` in the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: thanks. That was the problem! Just on the side: is it possible to do something like `OFS="\t\t"`. Because sometimes I need two of them in order to align the numbers correctly.

Comment: @uitty400 of course, you can test it with `echo "1 2 3" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t\t"} {print $1, $2}'`.

Comment: @uitty400 you probably need to say `BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="\t\t"}`. Or even `FS="\t"; OFS=FS FS`!! (I was surprised about it)